# In Sharepoint can you run a script when the user logs out

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

In SharePoint 2013

I have a script that shows a disclaimer.  This script creates a cookie and I wanted to delete the cookie or set it to expire when the user logs out.

Is that possible?

```
<p align="center">DISCLAIMER GOES HERE</p>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var agreement = GetCookie();

// checks for cookie and displays disclaimer alert if new user
if(agreement=="")
    {
    var decision = confirm("DISCLAIMER: GOES HERE \n\nClick Ok if you agree to the disclaimer or click Cancel to close this window. \n");
            if(decision == true)
                    {
                    // writes a cookie
                    var expiredays = 7;
                    var exdate=new Date()
                    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expiredays)
                    document.cookie="PartnerAgreement"+ "=" +escape("Agree To Disclaimer")+
                    ((expiredays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toGMTString())
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    // redirect
                    window.location = "/_layouts/signout.aspx";

                    // or close the browser window
                    //window.opener='x';
                    //window.close();
                    }
    }

// gets the Cookie if it exists
function GetCookie()
    {
    if (document.cookie.length>0)
            {
            c_name = "PartnerAgreement";
            c_start=document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=")
            if (c_start!=-1)
                    {
                    c_start=c_start + c_name.length+1
                    c_end=document.cookie.indexOf(";",c_start)
                    if (c_end==-1) c_end=document.cookie.length
                    return agreement = unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start,c_end))
                    }
            }
            return "";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly can try. When you press "Log out" you are redirected to SignOut.aspx page in `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS` folder. Try to add code to its script block before `window.close()` statement. Do not forget to do iisreset after changing aspx page.

Comment: It is bad practice to edit a default SharePoint page in the layouts folder. You better create a new page and set it as the new sign out page with the SharePoint Management Shell: `Set-SPCustomLayoutsPage -identity "Signout" -RelativePath "/_layouts/CustomSignout/Signout.aspx" -WebApplication "http://yourwebapplication"`. But apart from this I think this will be the way to go.

Comment: Yes, it is generally not very good to edit standard pages in layouts folder but in this case he needs all the same functionality as standard page plus some custom script. If he just make copy of standard page then it won't make any difference from your suggestion. Except he don't need to run any powershell scripts.

Comment: That's right, but with any SharePoint update your changes could be overwritten, if you just edit the page.